# Get UserId from the Session Id and Server URL

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, sessionid

I have a requirement, where I will be getting the Session Id and Server URL(parameters of a webservice method).

Say like this:

Session ID : 00D900000xxxxxx!ARUAQOb4VVoQR1UXlY_Hvuy1DdKdN6nSfnNJKYwPTF9R3tYuA2jzBsWXHIGDQUFL13iebnYSDKKC45H98TzVxxxxxxxxxx

Server URL :
https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/12.0/00D900000xxxxxx

Now i need to get the User Id(or any other user details) from these two.

Thanks in Advance!!

Nitin

Answer (score 2):

You could use the SOAP API, which has a [GetUserInfo](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo.htm) method. Calling this method will return a [GetUserInfoResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo_getuserinforesult.htm#topic-title) object, which will contain the user ID associated to the session.

Answer (score 1):

Adam, GetUserInfo method requires existing connection object which we can create by calling method, so I applied the following code and now everything works fine!

> ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
>   config.setAuthEndpoint("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/24.0/");
>   config.setServiceEndpoint("https://na14.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/24.0/00DXXXXXXXXXXXX");
>   config.setSessionId("00DXXXXXXXXXXXX!1AQ4AQO980Fmu25SOFQxxOlQN8zAaHOlnfdk._rZU2Vkf_CV0HJREqKavMLaPg9jtA9N517MNHLdLeF.aVkoZtnk2eu7u.XNn");
>   connection = new EnterpriseConnection(config); GetUserInfoResult
>   userInfo = connection.getUserInfo();

I used the same server URL and sessionId that I have received from query parameter string.

Comment: You could delete the whole answer then. But your code is still an useful sample and is a valid answer so why don't you edit it? Just remove the error and say "... and make sure the SessionId you're passing is not URLencoded" or something :)

Comment: Cool, first time I'm downvoting a question and upvoting an answer (downvoting because I'm afraid it's an attempt to capture values from cookies or sth like that and hijack session information).