# iFrame Authentication

Tags: java, security, authentication, iframe, salesforce

I am in the midway of integrating **salesforce.com with a legacy system via iFrame** link consisting of **orgId** as request parameter and legacy system(Java Application) upon getting orgId as request parameter check db of legacy system whether this orgId already exist or not (prior existence means Salesforce user has grant access to the legacy System Application), so question which remains unanswered is **if somehow orgId gets captured by intruder then they can access legacy system application** easily, so challenge is to stop any such attacks.
FYI both iFrame link and salesforce site runs on https protocol.

Comment: This question is too broad. You are asking "how do I implement internet security?" From the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: I am just asking if I can give more security to iFrame authentication other then using SSL, I think you should read question 1 more time to make yourself clear enough that it's not that broad that you are trying to convey here.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where the iFrame is, is the iFrame in your legacy app and pointing to Salesforce, or embedded in Salesforce and pointing to the legacy app?

Comment: Embedded in Salesforce and pointing to legacy app.

Comment: You might want to check out the Canvas (http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Canvas), a recent addition with sane authentication options. But at the moment they can be used only on Chatter tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the Org Id you could also pass the active Salesforce SessionId and ServerURL in the query string. The legacy app could then use these to establish a SOAP API session back to Salesforce and validate that the OrgId matches the session details.

Then the intruder would need to have full access to the current users Salesforce session to access the legacy app via the iframe. If they did, your security has already been sufficiently compromised that you have bigger issues.

Comment: Daniel, I am using SessionId and ServerURL in query String and when I try to establish connection through SOAP API, it throws following error. UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  `exceptionCode='INVALID_SESSION_ID'
 exceptionMessage='Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session'`

Comment: Please find code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133651/get-userid-from-the-session-id-and-server-url/13247989#13247989

Comment: My bad, sessionId was encoded, so I decoded and now I am able to establish connection via SOAP API/

Answer (score 0):

Rather then use a static orgId, you could use a dynamic token.
There are several ways you can implement it, for instance, you could design the token to be encrypted and contain both the orgId and a timestamp, and then generate the timestamp dynamically in salesforce and only allow tokens that are valid for X minutes/seconds (depends on how your users use the legacy app).

This won't prevent an intruder from getting access to the legacy app if they have access to the salesforce account (where the orgId is kept), to prevent that you need to stop using an orgId and rather use some kind of signup and generate a token that you can later revoke if someone misuses it.
That is when the user of the legacyapp signs up (or whatever process you have to originally save the orgId in salesforce), rather then keep the orgId, call the legacy app and generate a token (which is saved in the legacy app's db), which can be used later in the iFrame.